# Android Studio SDK not installed by default on Mac

Tags: android-studio

Newish to Mac and having installed Android Studio it doesn't seem to have installed the Android SDK.

Any search for installing Android SDK seems to just refer me to install Android Studio again which I've tried with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install via `brew` which will install to `/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`

**GoTo**: Android Studio > Configure > SDK Manager.

Then update the location of the SDK within Android Studio as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that seems to have sorted it!